# Customizing a Flow's Finish Behavior

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I've been trying to set a flows finish behaviour in lwc and it keeps restarting I see from the documentation I am meant to set the flowFinishBehavior attribute but how do I exactly set this? or at least I am getting a new Started on change event stating that it's restarting.

[image: messages]

Comment: Can you share some code to understand your use case better? And show visual flow also to see what is happening after finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it's flow-finish-behavior attribute on the flow not flowFinishBehavior as stated on the top.